# How to handle image upload in angular 5 Tiny MCE component?

Tags: angular, tinymce, angular5, tinymce-4

I am using TinyMCE editor in angular my angular 5 project, and want to handle image uploads, which I am currently not able to do.
Here is my current code:

```
<editor 
  name="questionStatement" 
  apiKey="somekey" 
  [init]='{
    plugins : [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
        "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
      ],
      toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image", 
      past_date_images: true,
      external_plugins: { tiny_mce_wiris: "https://www.wiris.net/demo/plugins/tiny_mce/plugin.js" },
      toolbar: "tiny_mce_wiris_formulaEditor, tiny_mce_wiris_formulaEditorChemistry"
    }'
  </editor>
```

I am following this code sample https://codepen.io/nirajmchauhan/pen/EjQLpV  , to handle image uploads. I don't understand, how do I pass the `file_picker_callback` function to the editor in angular ?

Is there any other way, how should I handle the image uploads ?

I have tried reading the documentation, but couldn't find anything. I have been stuck on this problem for a long time and it would be really great, if someone is able to help me with it.

Answer (score 5):

This is what worked for me (I am using `@tinymce/tinymce-angular`):

```
<editor [(ngModel)]="source" [init]="tinymceInit"></editor>
```

In the Constructor or Init:

```
...

this.tinymceInit = {
  plugins : [
    "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
    "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
    "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
    "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
  ],
  toolbar : 'formatselect | bold italic strikethrough forecolor backcolor | link | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify  | numlist bullist outdent indent  | removeformat',
  image_advtab : true,
  file_picker_callback : function(cb, value, meta) {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
    input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');

    // Note: In modern browsers input[type="file"] is functional without 
    // even adding it to the DOM, but that might not be the case in some older
    // or quirky browsers like IE, so you might want to add it to the DOM
    // just in case, and visually hide it. And do not forget do remove it
    // once you do not need it anymore.

    input.onchange = function() {
      var file = input.files[0];

      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function () {
        // Note: Now we need to register the blob in TinyMCEs image blob
        // registry. In the next release this part hopefully won't be
        // necessary, as we are looking to handle it internally.
        var id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
        var blobCache =  tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
        var base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];
        var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, base64);
        blobCache.add(blobInfo);

        // call the callback and populate the Title field with the file name
        cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    };

    input.click();
  }
}
```

Edit: To add, you can use that functino to upload files as well, as you know. I would much rather have the base64 data for the particular project I am working on.

Comment: where to get the object tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload

Comment: @JeevaJsb this was a few years ago. At that time, the object just worked, now, you would have to globally declare it.

Answer (score 2):

**Just to clarify, as of 2022, this is the correct way of implementing the image plugin in angular**

At the top of your component.ts, declare tinymce

```js
declare let tinymce: any;
```

In your init configuration, use this file_picker_callback (this one will not trigger any errors in your ts file)

```js
... rest of editor init
plugins: 'image',
toolbar: 'image',
image_advtab: true,
file_picker_callback: function(cb: any, value: any, meta: any) {
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
  input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');

  input.onchange = function () {
    var file = input.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function () {
      var id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
      var blobCache = tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
      var base64 = (reader.result as string).split(',')[1];
      var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, base64);
      blobCache.add(blobInfo);
      cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  };

  input.click();
}
```

You are done :)

Answer (score 2):

I use TinyMCE with Angular 13 and I upload images using the secured endpoint of a Spring Boot API.

I managed to implement TinyMCE image upload mostly thanks to this tutorial (a big thanks to the author) :

https://careydevelopment.us/blog/adding-images-in-a-wysiwyg-editor-with-tinymce-thymeleaf-and-spring-boot
[enter link description here][1]

To instantiate TinyMCE I use a service that implements the file_picker_callback and the images_upload_handler functions, needed for uploading images. Since I use an external secured Spring Boot API endpoint for image upload, I added the authorisation token to the request sent by the images_upload_handler function. Here is the service I used:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

declare let tinymce: any;

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TinyMceService {

constructor() {
}

/*
Function instantiating a customised TinyMCE textarea instance, identified 
by its id.
*/
initDefaultEditor(id: string): any {

tinymce.init({
  selector: '#' + id,
  toolbar_location: 'top',
  toolbar_align: 'left',
  toolbar_mode: 'wrap',
  resize: 'both',
  statusbar: true,
  file_picker_types: 'image',
  image_title: true,
  image_caption: true,
  image_advtab: true,
  image_uploadtab: false,
  images_reuse_filename: true,
  paste_data_images: true,
  a11y_advanced_options: true,

  /*
// depreciated since tinyMCE 5.3 version
  images_dataimg_filter(img: any): boolean {
  return !img.hasAttribute('internal-blob');  // blocks the upload of <img> elements with the attribute "internal-blob".
  },
  */

  plugins: ' save autosave preview print paste ' +
    'code fullscreen fullpage ' +
    'image link media  table template codesample hr charmap emoticons advlist lists insertdatetime ' +
    ' pagebreak nonbreaking anchor toc wordcount ' +
    ' searchreplace  help ',

  toolbar: 'undo redo| preview fullscreen | styleselect | fontselect | forecolor backcolor |bold italic underline strikethrough|' +
    'alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify|charmap emoticons image| numlist bullist table hr|link|outdent indent|searchreplace toc',


  /* The file_picker_callback function opens a file browsing dialogue and allows the user to pick an image.
  *  When an image is picked, the function calls the callback function images_upload_handler, that will
  * upload the image.*/
  file_picker_callback(callback: any, value: any, meta: any): any {


    // Provide image and alt text for the image dialog
    if (meta.filetype === 'image') {

      // create the file picker
      const input = document.createElement('input');
      input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
      input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');

      input.onchange = () => {
        // @ts-ignore
        const file = input.files[0];
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = () => {
          // const blobId = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
          // const blobCache = tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
          const blobCache = tinymce.get(id).editorUpload.blobCache;
          // @ts-ignore
          const base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];
          // const blobInfo = blobCache.create(blobId, file, base64);
          const blobInfo = blobCache.create(file.name.substring(0, file.name.lastIndexOf('.')), file, base64);
          blobCache.add(blobInfo);

          // call the callback and populate the Title field with the file name
          //  callback(blobInfo.blobUri(), {title: file.name, location: 'assets/images/' + file.name});
          callback(blobInfo.blobUri(), {title: file.name});

        };
        // read the file as a blob (binary object)
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      };
      // next line opens the file input on click
      input.click();
    }
  },


  images_upload_handler(blobInfo: any, success: any, failure: any): any {

    const TOKEN_HEADER_KEY = 'Authorization';
    const TOKEN_KEY = 'auth-token';
    const token = sessionStorage.getItem(TOKEN_KEY);

    // @ts-ignore
    const uploadImageApiUrl = window['cfgApiBaseUrl'] + window['editorApiImagesUploadPath'];
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = false;
    xhr.open('POST', uploadImageApiUrl);
    xhr.setRequestHeader(TOKEN_HEADER_KEY, 'Bearer ' + token);

    xhr.onload = () => {
      let json;

      // tslint:disable-next-line:triple-equals
      if (xhr.status != 200) {
        failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
        return;
      }
      json = xhr.responseText;

      const parsedJson = JSON.parse(json);
      // @ts-ignore
      success(parsedJson.message);
    };

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());
    xhr.send(formData);
  }
});

this.reloadEditor();
}

/*
If the textarea iframe was not loaded correctly, the iframe will have a 
length > 0.
In this case you should reload the page, thus triggering the textarea 
reload also.
*/
reloadEditor(): any {
const iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
if (iframe.length > 0) {
  window.location.reload();
}
}
}
```

To instantiate TinyMCE within a component, I call the service method within the ngOnInit method of the component's typescript file:

```
   this.tinyMceService.initDefaultEditor('editorTinyMCE');
```

And inside the html file I use a textare tag with the id used to initiate TinyMCE:

```
    <textarea
    class="form-control tiny-mce tinyMCE"
    formControlName="content"
    id="editorTinyMCE">
    </textarea>
```

I personally use TinyMCE within an Angular reactive form. To retrieve the data, i use :

```
    const html = tinymce.get('editorTinyMCE').getContent();
```

That's it, I hope this post will help someone.